# How to use regular expression to format json file

Tags: java, json, regex

I want to write a text file to a json file using regular expressions with java.

Meaning I want a text file containing this:

5.2 Hello

Sentence 1. Sentence 2.

To become this:

```
{"Chapter": "5.2",
  "Title": "Hello",
  "Text": "Sentence 1. Sentence 2."}
```

I have some code to match certain fields in my text file and output it to json, however I'm not sure how to break the json into the sections I need using regex.

I'm attempting this:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile((\d\.\d)(.*?)(?=\d\.\d|$));
 Matcher m = p.matcher(readFile(text));
 while(m.find()) {
 obj.put("Chapter", m.group());
 System.out.println(obj);}
```

But this only outputs the chapter field followed by the rest of the text. I'm not sure how to split this data into the chapter, title and text fields.

Input:

5.2 Hello

Sentence 1. Sentence 2.

Current Output is:

`{"Chapter": "5.2 Hello Sentence 1. Sentence 2."}`

But I need it to be this:

`{"Chapter": "5.2",
   "Title": "Hello",
   "Text": "Sentence 1. Sentence 2."}`

Any help?

Comment: May you provide a clearer example of input and output? Are there consecutive chapters to fit in one json object?

Comment: @horcrux I added in the specific inputs and outputs

Comment: @Alexander Farber The extra comma was a mistake, I edited it out. How would I use Gson to parse? I thought regex was the best way

Comment: @Alexander Farber Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your input is with format:

5.2 Hello \n

Whatever text...

Your way of thinking is correct. Since you want to divide the original text into three sections. You just need to make use of the border between the sections. For example, "5.2" and "Hello" have a space (\s) in bewteen, "Hello" has a new line (or maybe another space) before main text.

You can try:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+(.*?)\\n(.*$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if(m.find()) {
        obj.put("Chapter", m.group(1));
        obj.put("Title", m.group(2));
        obj.put("Text", m.group(3));
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
```

Your previous way of using group is incorrect, because the number of groups always depends on how many pairs of bracket you have for your pattern.compile(). Since you will have three groups in total, simply use the index to get their value.

Note: group(0) is the whole thing, so the first group is accessed by index 1.